# Badges in Review Section

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I have never understood why do the following badges appear in the review section:

- Civic Duty
- Copy Editor
- Electorate

These have nothing to do with the review process as such.
Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: I don't know why, but *Copy Editor* has been there [since at least November 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/more-badge-progress-indicators). Perhaps `/review` was the best option out of available places to put it, back then.

Comment: I find it uncomfortable to see the status of these badges only *after* you have started a review. So to see the status only, you have to find a review queue with zero entries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those badges *are* related to the review process:

- You can edit questions and answers in the suggested edits queue, hence Copy Editor.
- You can vote in the first posts queue, hence Civic Duty and Electorate.
- A long, long time ago you could vote in the close and low quality queues too (correct me if I'm wrong).
- You can still open the question through the link and downvote, if you think it's needed (for example, if you think that the question needs to be downvoted, but not closed).

So those are the badges that you gain for the activities that you are expected to undertake while reviewing.

Comment: I know that this is technically the wrong place to point it out, but "They don't have nothing" is really confusing to read. Perhaps "They do have something" would work better?

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Why would this be the wrong place to point that out? That sort of thing is exactly what comments are for.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Mainly because that's a grammar thing and not programming/meta programming

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I don't think it matters whether the comment is about a programming error or not. Any constructive criticism is welcome. (See the "When Should I Comment" section in the description for the [Comment Everywhere privlege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).)

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight this is meta.SO... It is not about programming. Plus I don't see why this shouldn't be not not legit.

Comment: @Theolodis however, talking about what to talk about on meta.SO is off topic on meta.SO.  Please talk about that on meta.meta.SO.  [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_sharp)

Comment: @Ajedi32 I know it doesn't matter, that's why I commented on it. It's just... meta.SO is for site discussion, so pointing out a (non-programming, non-site related) grammatical error on a post seems off-topic to me.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight *Posts* on meta.SO are for discussion of the site, *comments* are for discussion of the post that they're on, including anything that would improve the quality (such as spelling and grammar changes - or you could just (suggest an) edit).