# Why is the only way to find the number of edits you have made in the review section?

Tags: discussion, edits, badges

The badges related to editing (E.G. [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white)) all require a certain number of edits.  However, there is no obvious place to see the number of edits you have made.  There is one place, and one place only (that I know of) where you can view this count, and that is by hovering over the progress bar on one of the [review stats pages](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats).  This makes very little sense.  (While there is [some explanation as to why the information is there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270700/badges-in-review-section?cb=1), it doesn't explain the absence of the information elsewhere).

This information should probably be displayed on the user profile, and on the badge's page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the number of revisions in your profile, by visiting the activity tab and then sorting by "revisions" in the sub-options. It will show you the total number of post edits that you've made or, for you, have been approved (since you have to suggest edits).

Your link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3991344/pokechu22?tab=activity&sort=revisions - it says you've made 155 revisions.

However, you should keep in mind that **this is not the number of edits that count towards the badges**. The badges have more stringent requirements on what counts and what doesn't, whereas your profile just lists all the revisions you've made. The numbers listed on your profile and listed in the badge progress indicator will not necessarily match each other.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  So there actually is one.  It still would be useful information on to have on the badge's page, though.

Comment: I agree.  It would be easier if there was a tab.  Its confusing when the badge is for "edits" but its called "revisions" in the profile.